# How to check if many-to-many list is empty with django-filter?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-filter

I am using django-rest-framework with django-filter to implement filtering. 
Let's say I have following result:

```
{
    "id": 13,
    "created": "2017-06-21T01:08:49.790254Z",
    "updated": "2017-07-21T10:25:51.706730Z",
    "toylist": [],
}
```

How do I implement filtering so I can check if the toylist array is empty? For example, something like: `/toys/?toylist__isnull=True`

Comment: Can you post your current view/viewset class?

Comment: Yes, here it is:                                                                                       
class ToysViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
 queryset = Toys.objects.all().order_by('-created')
 serializer_class = ToysSerializer
 filter_class = ToysFilter

Comment: And the `ToysFilter` class because that's the one handling the filtering

Comment: i do have toysfilter class

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was a relatively simple fix:

```
class ToysFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    toylist__isnull = filters.BooleanFilter(name='toylist', method='list_is_empty')

class Meta:
    model = Toys
    fields = {
        'id':['exact'],
        'created':'__all__',
        'updated':'__all__',
     }

def list_is_empty(self, qs, name, value):
    isnull = not value
    lookup_expr = LOOKUP_SEP.join([name, 'isnull'])

    return qs.filter(**{lookup_expr: isnull}).distinct()
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't necessary to use a method here. More simply, you could do the following:

```py
class ToysFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    toylist__isnull = filters.BooleanFilter(name='toylist', lookup_expr='isnull', distinct=True)
```